# How to deny a range of IP address which follow a pattern in ufw?

Tags: networking, ufw, ip

I want to block all incoming ip of the pattern `192.168.*.*` (this is an example). I tried `ufw deny from 192.168.*.* to any` but it gives this error.

> ERROR: Bad source address

How can I block a range of IP address which follow a specific pattern?

Comment: Maybe try to use a mask `ufw deny from 192.168.0.1/16 to any`. Here is more information about the masks : http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/subnetting-subnet-masks-explained/

Comment: Does ufw have a `man` page?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, ufw doesn't support wildcards (*).

To have a rule apply to a range of addresses, you should use a subnet mask or CIDR notation.

Your example using CIDR:

```
ufw deny from 192.168.0.0/16
```

Your example using subnet mask:

```
ufw deny from 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Comment: Useful link: https://mxtoolbox.com/subnetcalculator.aspx